# Show that $im(f\circ f) \subseteq im(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map from the real vector space V to V. Show that $im(f\circ f) \subseteq im(f)$.

I need to show that $\forall v \in V: v\in im(g\circ g) \Rightarrow v\in im(g)$. Let v be arbitrary, I then need to show that if $g(g(w))=v$, for some $w\in V$, then there exists an $u\in V : g(u)=v$. But I don't know how to show this, can anybody help please?

Comment: Let $u = g(w)$.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $f(V)\subset V$ so $$\operatorname{im}(f\circ f)=f(f(V))\subset f(V)=\operatorname{im}(V)$$

Answer (score 1):

Every map $f$ preserves inclusions, i.e., when $A\subset B$ for any two subsets then $fA\subset fB$.

So, you get your claim observing that $f(V)\subset V$ implies $f(fV)\subset f(V)$.

Comment: done, ...,fixed, ...healed